# Is there a way to restore to previous version in Mac OS X after installing the update?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, finder

In my Mac OSX I recently updated my Mac from 10.6.5 to 10.6.6.

After I installed the 10.6.6 version, I get error in Finder as below:

**The application Finder can't be opened**

Just around a minute after restarting my Mac everytime I get the error from Finder and then everthing stops working.

I have lots of important data in my Mac but now I cant take a backup of it as Finder stops working.

So, Is there a way in Mac where I can revert back to 10.6.5 version?

What are my options?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to "downgrade" to an earlier version.

Install a full 10.6.x from DVD and use the 10.6.5 combo updater afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But then will my data be safe. Will it not be lost? Is there any way I can backup my data now?

Comment: @PARTH If you have a second Mac, look into booting up in "Target Disk Mode". This way, your Mac is just like an external FireWire drive and you can copy your data off it. You also can install Mac OS X on a drive containing a previous system, and have the option to preserve that data during installation. Just put in the installation DVD and check your options.

Answer (score 0):

It won't exactly get you back to the previous version, but the way to deal with this is to put the system restore CD that came with your Mac (or the standalone Snow Leopard disk, if your Mac didn't come with 10.6) in your Mac, then restart while holding down the 'C' key to boot from it. You can then re-install the operating system. Make sure you don't deselect the option to "preserve users and network settings", and all your data and programs should still be there. Once you've re-installed Mac OS X, you can run Software Update to get you back up to 10.6.6.