# The application Finder can't be opened. -10810

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, finder

I am getting an error as shown in the screenshot.

This started happening after I updated my **Mac OS X from 10.6.5 to 10.6.6**.

Problem is that **Finder stops working 5 mins after the restart** and all the other aplications including Xcode 3.2.5, iPhone simulator, safari,etc stops working.

Everytime I have to restart the Mac as all the things hang.

What could be wrong?

What could be a permanent fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to continue with this question or have you already decided to downgrade/reinstall Mac OS X via [here](http://superuser.com/questions/234190/is-there-a-way-to-restore-to-previous-version-in-mac-os-x-after-installing-the-up)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guys for all your replies.

Finally had to re-install a fresh copy of Mac OS X 10.6 and upgrade back to 10.6.5. So No fix worked. Had to re-install Mac OS X.

Hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

After restarting and before the Finder hangs, open the `Console` application.  It's in `/Applications/Utilities`.  Then take a look for error messages in system.log or other the available logs.  If necessary, update your question with additional information from there.

Comment: @Ned : Thanks for your input. How can I see system.log? Is there any specific command for it. When I type system.log in Terminal it shows Invalid Command. so how can I see system log and other logs

Comment: By launching the Console application as I suggested; double-click on it.  If you have access to a Terminal window, you can look in the various directories where logs reside (you may need administrator privileges).  Try: `cd /var/log` and `ls -ltr` to see available logs in order of last write time; and `more system.log` to view the system log, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a verify disk? You can do this from single user mode or from your install media. [The full Apple Article is here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1417), but I've included the important points below. You may also wish to verify and repair permissions. As I'm a newbie, I can't post more than one link :-. There are other guides on how to accomplish that with the `diskutil` command.

1. Install Media - GUI
  1. Start computer while holding down the **option** key. You can then select whether to boot from the hard drive or some other media.
  2. After booting into the installation media, select your language.

     Now, find the **Utilities** menu and select **Disk Utility**.

     You can now select the media on which your operating system is installed.

     Now, select "Verify Disk" from "First Aid".

     Make some coffee or tea; this might take a while.
2. Single User Mode - Command Line
  1. Restart the computer.
  2. Right as it starts up again, hold down **Command + S**.
  3. You should see a black screen as you drop into Single User Mode. You will have root access, so be careful!
  4. You'll run the following command: `/sbin/fsck -fy`.
  5. Make some coffee or tea; this might take a while.
3. Once the verification is complete, try restarting and see what happens.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Yes I did. But with no success. Finally had to re-install a fresh copy of Mac OS X 10.6 and upgrade back to 10.6.5